# Has the SHA1 fingerprint been uploaded

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angular2-nativescript

I am currently developing an app on NativeScript Framework and Firebase Authentication, Storage and Database.

However, I got the error below when I try to login to Google Authentication. 
JS: Has the SHA1 fingerprint been uploaded? Sign-in status: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}***"

Below is the code,

```
 loginGoogle():void{
        firebase.login({
            type: firebase.LoginType.GOOGLE
        }).then(
        function (result) {
            JSON.stringify(result);
        },
        function (errorMessage) {
            console.log(errorMessage);
            }
        );
    }
```

I have added the SHA1 Fingerprint to Firebase Console, by running the keytool's command in command prompt.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue, the root cause was I missed out the debug keystore in the Firebase. What I have uploaded earlier it was the **Release** keystore.

After I uploaded the Debug keystore and it works as expected now. FYI, the **Debug** keystore path should be in Window's user profile folder and the password should be **BLANK.**

Please refer to this page for the key generating.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

I hope this will helps!